# WPF using StackPanel within a a menu

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem, stackpanel

I have a wpf application where I am using a side menu.  In one section of the menu I have a Header menuitem and two sub menuitems.  I change the background on the two sub menuitems to show a difference.  There is a slight gap between the two sub menuitems with a different color.  I want the background of both sub menuites to be the same with not gap in between.  Here is my menu code:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="miReplaceLF" Header="Replace Line Feeds" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          ToolTip="Replace all line feeds in choosen fields with the replacement character." />
<MenuItem x:Name="smiDBFile" Header="DataBase Table"
           Click="MenuItem_Click_RLFDBDatabase" Background="#FFBEEBF7"
           Margin="15,0,0,0"
           ToolTip="Replace line feeds on fields in a database table." />
<MenuItem x:Name="smiExcelTextFile" Header="Excel or Text File" Height="24" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="MenuItem_Click_RLFExcelText" Background="#FFBEEBF7"
            Margin="15,0,0,0"
            ToolTip="Choose a Excel/Text File." />
```

I tried putting the two sub menuitems within a stackpanel.  This gives me the ability to have the uniform background I want but the sub menuitems are shifted to the right way too much.  I just want a small indent on the two sub menuitem.  I can't find a way to get the menuitems alligned to the left.  Here is the code with the stackpanel.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="miReplaceLF" Header="Replace Line Feeds" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ToolTip="Replace all line feeds in choosen fields with the replacement character." />
        <StackPanel Background="#FFBEEBF7">
            <MenuItem x:Name="smiDBFile" Header="DataBase Table"
                   Click="MenuItem_Click_RLFDBDatabase" Background="#FFBEEBF7"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   ToolTip="Replace line feeds on fields in a database table." />
            <MenuItem x:Name="smiExcelTextFile" Header="Excel or Text File" Height="24" 
                    Click="MenuItem_Click_RLFExcelText" Background="#FFBEEBF7"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    ToolTip="Choose a Excel/Text File." />
        </StackPanel>
```

Here is the full XAML code, this has been changed to use the suggestions by Ed Plunkett

```
<Window x:Class="TextUtilities.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextUtilities"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Text Utilites" x:Name="TextUtils" Height="420" Width="900" Left="100" Top="30" 
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#FFDBF4FB">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style 
            TargetType="MenuItem" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" 
            x:Key="RLFItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBEEBF7" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Margin="0,2,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" 
              BorderThickness="0,2,2,0" BorderBrush="#FFE0E0E0" Background="#FFDBF4FB">
            <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="spItemsPanel" Background="#FFDBF4FB" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemsPanel>


            <MenuItem x:Name="miReplaceLF" Header="Replace Line Feeds" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                ToolTip="Replace all line feeds in choosen fields with the replacement character."/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="smiDBFile" Header="DataBase Table" Height="24" 
                Style="{StaticResource RLFItem}" Click="MenuItem_Click_RLFDBDatabase"
                ToolTip="Replace line feeds on fields in a database table." />
            <MenuItem x:Name="smiExcelTextFile" Header="Excel or Text File" Height="24"
                Style="{StaticResource RLFItem}" Click="MenuItem_Click_RLFExcelText" 
                ToolTip="Choose a Excel/Text File." />

            <MenuItem x:Name="miCreateLF" Header="Create Line Feeds" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Replace all the replacement characters with line feeds." />
            <MenuItem x:Name="miViewTextField" Header="View Text Field" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="MenuItem_Click_ViewTextField" ToolTip="Display the contents of a text field.  Allows you to see how the data will be displayed in the UI." />
            <MenuItem x:Name="miViewSPTEXT" Header="View SPTEXT" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="MenuItem_Click_ViewSPTEXT" ToolTip="Display field sptd_text from table sptextdt.  Allows you to see how the data will be displayed in the UI." />
            <MenuItem x:Name="miSPlitLargeFile" Header="Split Large File" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="MenuItem_Click_SLF" ToolTip="Split large files, over 60MB into smaller files." />
            <MenuItem x:Name="miHowTo" Header="How To" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="MenuItem_Click_HowTo" ToolTip="Instructions on how to use the SPText Utilities." />
            <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="MenuItem_Click_Close" />
        </Menu>

        <Grid x:Name="grdRLFDatabase" Visibility="Visible" Height="350" Margin="155,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtRLFDBTitle" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="Process to clean a database table and create a pipe delimited text file. You may type in a server instance or select one from the list.  Once a server is choosen please cliack the 'Load DB Info' button." 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" Margin="10,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="659" FontFamily="Arial" 
                     FontSize="16" Padding="5,1,1,1" Background="#FFDBF4FB" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBInstance" Content="Enter Database Instance:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBInstances" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" IsEditable="True"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnRLFDBLoadDBInfo" Content="Load DB Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="475,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Click="btnRLFDBLoadDBInfo_Click" Background="#FFEEFFFF" ToolTip="Click here after choosing or typing in the datbase instance.  This will populate the database list."/>
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBName" Content="Choose Database:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBName" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="cbxRLFDBName_SelectionChanged" ToolTip="Once a database is choosen the table list will automatically be populated."/>
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBTableName" Content="Choose Table:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBTableName" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" IsEditable="True" />
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBOutputName" Content="Choose Output Folder:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtRLFDBOutputFolder" x:FieldModifier="public" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="189,222,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" />
            <Button x:Name="btnRLFDBBrowseFolder" Content="Browse..." x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="475,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Background="#FFEEFFFF" Click="btnRLFDBBrowseFolder_Click" ToolTip="Choose the folder where the text file will be saved to.  The file will be named the same as a the table with '_duc' appended to the end."/>
            <Button x:Name="btnRLFDBSubmit" Content="Submit" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="261,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Background="#FFEEFFFF" Click="btnRLFDBSubmit_Click"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="grdRLFExcelText" Visibility="Hidden" Height="320" Width="750" Margin="150, 0, 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFFileInfo" Content="Process to replace Line Feeds in text fields." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="583" Height="30" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18.667" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFFileName" Content="Enter the filename:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162" Height="30" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtRLFFileName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="186,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FFDBF4FB" TextChanged="txtRLFFileName_TextChanged" />
            <Button x:Name="btnRLFFileBrowse" Content="Browse..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="630,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Background="#FFDBF4FB" Click="btnRLFFileBrowse_Click"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFOutputFolder" Content="Choose output folder:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="30" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtRLFOutputFolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="186,138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FFDBF4FB" TextChanged="txtRLFOutputFolder_TextChanged"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnRLFFolderBrowse" Content="Browse..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="630,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Background="#FFDBF4FB" Click="btnRLFFolderBrowse_Click"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblRLFFieldDelim" Content="Field Delimiter:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" Height="30" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtRLFFieldDelim" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="312,206,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FFDBF4FB" TextChanged="txtRLFFileName_TextChanged" MaxLength="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="chbxRLFHeaders" Content="Has Header Row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="430,208,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Checked="chbxRLFHeaders_Checked" Unchecked="chbxRLFHeaders_Unchecked"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnRLFSubmit" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,259,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82" Height="31" Background="#FFDBF4FB" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Click="btnRLFSubmit_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the Margin to 0,0,0,0 on the stackpanel element and see if there is any change?

Comment: @Daniel AG -- Yes I tried that, didn't help.  The issue is that  the menu subitem content looks like it becomes center and doesn't change if I add HorizontalAlignment="Left"  I just can't figure out hot to get everything left aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a MenuItem style which changes Padding or Margin (your choice; try both) and background color for the menu items you apply it to, and then set it on whichever items you chose:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style 
            TargetType="MenuItem" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" 
            x:Key="SpecialItem"
            >
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBEEBF7" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

...

```
    <MenuItem Header="Foo" />
    <MenuItem Header="Bar" Style="{StaticResource SpecialItem}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Baz" Style="{StaticResource SpecialItem}" />
```

The mouse-hover state for those will look a little funny, unfortunately. With the default WPF `MenuItem` template, or at least the one I'm seeing here, you need to replace the entire control template to change that. We can go there if you need to; let me know.

### Update

How to add an image to a Stack Overflow question: Edit the question, then click the "add picture" icon which is highlighted in orange.

[image]

Comment: How is this different then the first way I did it?  I tried this but I still have the gap between the two SpecialItem sub menuitems.  I was thinking that the stackpanel would give me a block behind the two sub menuitems that I can change the background on, which it does but the sub menuitems text is centered instead od left justified.

Comment: @Cass No gap here. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is different here, I copied your code.  I did just add my outer Menu definition in case there is something there causing the issue.

Comment: @Cass Can you add a screenshot of the gap to your question?

Comment: Can I save screen shots here?

Comment: @Cass Put the file wherever you want, but the only place I'm going to look for the image is in your question.

Comment: I have no idea how to add an image here

Comment: Here is the link to it https://1drv.ms/w/s!Almt-FZeaycRnGwSOe-xat5hMKyb  The gap is a little hard to see here but when run it is more noticeable

Comment: @Cass See update to my answer about how to add images.

Comment: If you give me complete XAML maybe I can reproduce it.

Comment: @Cass Where what is? Put it in your question. Don't play games with me, I'm trying to help you. The purpose of this site is to collect answers to questions. A link to an external site, hidden in comments to an answer, is not a useful addition to your question.

Comment: I am sorry, I;m not playing games with you.  I put the screenshot and xaml code in word docs in my OneDrive.  I grabbed a link to those files and added them here.  I tried the link in my browser and it worked.  I have never shared images or documents with anyone here so I am not exactly sure how to accomplish that.  I really appreciate your help and I'm not trying to mess with you, I really am not sure how to share items with you.

Comment: @Cass I told you what to do, but you'd rather play games. Good luck solving your problem.

Comment: I am sorry but I missed what you showed earlier. I am working my job at the same time and was rushing.  I am sorry that you feel I was playing you.  That is not who I am.  At the same time when I ask a question I continue to investigate fixes and sometimes miss communications.  I have always appreciated all the help I have received on this forum.  However I am a human and do make mistakes or miss a communication.  I am sorry for that.  I will no longer bother you.

Comment: I'm not too much bothered by "who you are", I just care what you do. If you can see your way clear to pasting the XAML into your question I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I have edited the initial question with the full xaml.  I believe this is the correct way to post it.  Thank you

Comment: @Cass This XAML is a nightmare. You should learn to use styles, and format the stuff readably. I'm going through it by hand removing all the event handlers so it'll build.

Comment: @Cass See update. You need to set BorderThickness to zero as well. That solves it for me.  If you go into the Design mode of the XAML designer, you can right click on an item and go to "Edit Template" | "Edit a Copy", and see exactly how the control is put together. I spotted a thing using the BorderThickness, tried that, and that was it.

Comment: That worked.  Just what I was looking for/  Thanks for the tip on styles I will look into it. I am fairly new to wpf & c# and self taught.  Thank you